# C# DataGrid not filling up when called from other Class

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid in my wpf application. This datagrid is filled from DataSet. When I call my method Aktualizuj() everything works fine. The problem is whenever i call it from another class its triggering but datagrid remain unchanged.

Main main class

```
namespace MenadzerTicketow
{
    public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
            public void Aktualizuj()
        {
            try
            {
                //Some Code
                string selectStr = ("select * from " + aktywnatabela + " order by id desc");
                SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectStr, Start.m_dbConnection);
                DataSet dset = new DataSet();
                int i = myAdapter.Fill(dset);
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = dset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                //MessageBox.Show(dset.GetXml().ToString()); //DataSet is being filled correctyl, thats not a case
                //Some
                //Code
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had added code below, but problem did not dissapear.

```
 dataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
 dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

And from here I call Aktualizuj()

```
namespace MenadzerTicketow
{
    public partial class SDMWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        //Some Code

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var p = new MainWindow();
            p.Aktualizuj();
            p.Close();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please explain your problem in more detail. Like which is your MainWindow and from Where you are opening SDMWindow etc.

Comment: SDMWindow is opened in MainWindow by button ` SDMWindow win4 = new SDMWindow();  win4.Show();`
My problem is that `Aktualizuj()` when called from `SDMWindow` it is seems to working fine but dataGrid is remain unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code creates a *new instance* of the MainWindow:

```
var p = new MainWindow();
```

Since you never call the Show() method on it you will never actually see it.

For the DataGrid in the *already opened instance* of your MainWindow to be affected you need to get a reference to this specific window instance and call the Aktualizuj() method on this one. You could use the Application.Current.Windows collection to get a reference to the window:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow p = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (p != null)
        p.Aktualizuj();

    this.Close();
}
```

Or you could use the Application.Current.MainWindow provided that the window is actually your application's main window:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow p = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
    if (p != null)
        p.Aktualizuj();

    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) It worked and now I understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your variable `aktywnatabela` the same in both cases? As this is MainWindow, then probably all initializing actions are done but does the DataSet object have the same rows loaded from DB as in the working case?

Comment: Yes `aktywnatabela` is the same, but I think it is not important because the dataset is feeling OK (I checked it by using `MessageBox.Show(dset. GetXml (). ToString ());` )
Dataset rows should change, when I call a method `Aktualizuj()` from a button located in main class then new rows are added.
After calling from other class I see that `dset`contains new data, so probably problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Just kindly try this approach which I use to control Parent window from child window. Hope this help..

```
foreach (Window win in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>())
    {
        var mainWin = ((MainWindow)win);
        mainWin.Aktualizuj();
    }
```